# Some mandatory parameters are missing ("url_tag") to generate a URL for route "customUrl". Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to break out a resource ("fans") into separate routes so I can have custom urls for the individual resource pages, as opposed to using just $id.

So instead of this:

```
Route::resource('fans', 'FansController');
```

I have broken it into this:

```
Route::get('fans/{url_tag}', array('as' => 'customUrl', function($url_tag)
{
    $fan = Fan::where('url_tag','=',$url_tag);
    return View::make('fans.show', compact('fan'));
}))
->where('url_tag', '[A-Za-z]+');

Route::get('fans/{id}', function($id)
{
    // do something with $id or
    return Redirect::route('customUrl');
})
->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

In the fans controller, I have this:

```
public function show($id)
        {
        $fan = Fan::find($id);      
        return View::make('fans.show', compact('fan'))
            ->with('fans', Fan::all())
            ->with('latest_fan_likes', Fanartist::latest_profile_fan_likes($id));
}
```

Basically I would like the page /fans/$id to appear as /fans/$url_tag (where url_tag is another column in the db, that is unique).  But I would like it to have all of the properties of the resource, so I can call $fan->column directly.

When I run this, I get the error:

Some mandatory parameters are missing ("url_tag") to generate a URL for route "customUrl".

Any idea what is going on or what is wrong? I am using Laravel 4.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are trying to generate an URL, somewhere else in your code, in a controller or even a view, something like (may not be exactly that!):

```
URL::route('customUrl');

or 

route('customUrl');
```

But you need to provider the `url_tag`:

```
URL::route('customUrl', array('url_tag' => 'something');
```

For you could be something like:

```
URL::route('customUrl', array('url_tag' => $fan->url_tag);
```

Comment: For the 'something' portion, how do I point it to the value I have for each user, the column in the table fans "url_tag"?

Comment: You better show the code you are using to build that url, so we can see what you are trying to do, but basically you would do `URL::route('customUrl', array('url_tag' => $user->name)` or `URL::route('customUrl', array('url_tag' => $fan->url_tag)`, depends on your code...

Comment: that's all the code I have that relates to this part of the resource that's relevant.

Comment: is that relevant to this?  It's just show.blade.php in the /fans/views folder.  I use $fan->column syntax to get the properties for the resource for the page I am on (so /fans/1 is the first row of the table, etc.., so $fan->id appears as 1, etc...)